# Working with large data set in C

Tags: c, data-structures, dataset, bigdata

I have a text file with more then 4 million rows. Each row gives the detail of a road link i.e. the coordinates of the start and end node, the node id's, the link id etc. I will first extract data from the text file into two data structure, the first will hold the Link id and corresponding begin and end node id. The second data structure will hold the node id and the x and y coordinates of the correspoding node. I will then be working on these two data structure to find the path from a given origin and destination node.

My C skills have become a bit rusty and I was wondering what would be the best way to store and access the data considering the size.

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe just use data base ?

Comment: @Dabo. Thank You ..I am look into the use of database

Comment: @LipikaDeka What are the sizes of your data structures?

Comment: @LeeDuhem I have not read the data from the text file. The text file is 748,408 KB

Comment: @LipikaDeka I am asking the sizes your data structures, i.e. `sizeof(struct s1)` and `sizeof(struct s2)`, and `s1` and `s2` are the data structures you are going to use to store your data, not the size of your data file.

Comment: By the way, because you are using a text file as your data file, there are lots of unnecssary characters in it, such as field separators, newlines, and so on, so the in memory representation of your data may cost much less memory compared to its in text representation.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Like I said I have not as yet read my data from file into data structure. But if I estimate according to the data type in each, The size of each should be around 50 MB

Comment: Can you not understand the meaning of `sizeof(struct s1)`? Whatsoever, 50MB is quite small. You can allocate it dynamically by using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sounds like that much data to me. I'd start with something like this:

```
struct link;
struct node {
    struct link **links;
    int nlinks;
    /* whatever else you need to describe the node. */
};
struct link {
    struct node *n1, *n2;
};
```

Drop the nodes into a tree or hash table or some other efficient way to look up the node when reading the text file, for each line, allocate a link, look up the start and end nodes (allocate if necessary), grow their array of links, insert the links into the arrays.

Worst case is if each link has two unique nodes, so your overhead is "number of links" * (2*sizeof(struct node) + 2 * sizeof(struct link *) + sizeof(struct link)) which on a 64 bit machine should be around 256MB of data plus whatever additional information you want to store about the nodes, plus overhead for the lookup table for the nodes. If you use an inline avl tree, that's 24 bytes extra for the tree linkage, and 24 bytes for (64 bit) coordinates and node IDs (if you need them at all), you're still below half a gigabyte of data to work with.

If the node IDs are contiguous, you can get away with far less memory and just one data structure since you can put the nodes in an array and instead of the links, just save the node ID of the other side of the link and you're down to below 100MB in the worst case.